# SQL: Select distinct - without highcase/lowcase duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, case-sensitive

My query:

```
SELECT distinct [ID], [IDGROUP], [DESCRIPTION]
FROM table
```

My result problem:

1, 1, Hello 
1, 1, hello

How can I set a filter where I do not select duplicates where the difference is only the high/low case letter??

Comment: you can always skip the distinct and use a `GROUP BY [ID], [IDGROUP], UPPER([DESCRIPTION])`. Should give you the desired result i believe.

Comment: Are you sure its SQL Server, because distinct seems to ignore case

Comment: SELECT distinct [ID], [IDGROUP], [DESCRIPTION]
FROM table COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: GROUP BY did not work...
Yes, I´m using SQL Server 2008R2 and distinct gives these values :(

Comment: It will depending on the set up of the server itself.  Try specifying the case sensitivity in the query. As above.

Comment: Don´t have access to the server config :(

Comment: You dont need to.  You can override the settings in the query.  I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running this query.

`SELECT distinct [ID], [IDGROUP], [DESCRIPTION] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS FROM table`

Here you are basically saying ignore case on the DESCRIPTION column

CI = Case insensitive
AS = Accent sensitive.

Comment: OK, I had the Collate in the wrong position first time running it. This does work like a charm, thanks Fred :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess mysql engine does not duplicate based on letter case by default. 
That is both Hello and hello is considered same.

Comment: This will depend on the case sensitivity of the server set up. When the server is set up you can set the case sensitivity so one server will or could display different results to another.

Comment: Why have 2 people upvoted this? It doesn't remotely answer the question. It just claims that the situation in the question shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way but this worked for me:

```
SELECT distinct [ID], [IDGROUP], Upper([DESCRIPTION]) as [DESCRIPTION]
FROM table
```

Comment: it works,  but it changes all description to uppercase.